# Placing a Dictionary inside Viewbag

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

I'm trying to access a Dictionary in my View . But the following syntax :

```
@{
    var indexList = Viewbag.IndexList as Dictionary<int,long>;
}
```

doesnt work : `The name 'Viewbag' does not exist in the current context` 

P.S. :Tried placing '@' before Viewbag ,still doesn't work.

Can someone help ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

is it not ViewBag?

```
var indexList = ViewBag.IndexList as Dictionary<int,long>;
```

Comment: isn't that exactly what i wrote above ?

Comment: Case sensitive. Capitalization is important - It's the difference between: Helping your Uncle Jack off a horse, and: Helping your uncle jack off a horse... Very important!

Comment: Damn , now I feel bad. Spent half an hour trying to find the solution.
Sleep deprivation is not a good solution. Thanks , I will accept answer asap

Comment: have to add library MVC i think

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
var indexList = this.ViewBag.IndexList as Dictionary<int,long>;
```